# Consulta para asociar el campo de una tabla con su valor por defecto

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Estoy haciendo una consulta grande para generar un diccionario de datos, donde estoy indicando a cada campo de la tabla si es fk, pk, si tuviera designado un valor por default (CONSTRAINT-- DEFAULT()). Y es en este último que no puedo asociar el campo con su posible valor por default (si es que lo tuviese).

Un posible resultado sería de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que no se entiende tu pregunta; ¿necesitas el código completo para esa consulta o solamente para resolver la parte del `DEFAULT`?

Comment: Bueno, creo que todo va amarrado, lo puse a modo de ejemplo, pero quisiera al menos una idea de cómo podría asociar los campos con sus valores por `DEFAULT`

Answer (score 0):

Te puede servir la siguiente consulta a tablas de sistema (metadatos) que incluye los campos que mencionas en tu pregunta y otros más:

```
SELECT
  o.name as [Tabla], o.crdate as [Creacion tabla],
  c.colid as [ID campo], c.name as [Nombre campo],
  t.name as [Tipo campo], 
  c.length as [Tamaño], c.xprec as [Precision], c.xscale as [Escala],
  CAST(c.isnullable as bit) as [Acepta nulos],
  ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) as [Llave primaria],
  CAST(ISNULL(fk.referenced_column_id, 0) as bit) AS [Llave foranea],
  ISNULL(sm.text, '') as [Valor DEFAULT]
FROM sysobjects o
INNER JOIN syscolumns c ON o.id = c.id
INNER JOIN systypes t ON c.xusertype = t.xusertype
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = o.id AND ic.column_id = c.colid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.syscomments sm ON sm.id = c.cdefault
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.foreign_key_columns fk ON fk.parent_object_id = o.id AND fk.parent_column_id = c.colid
WHERE o.type = 'u'
```

La consulta filtra los objetos tipo `'u'` (objetos creados por el usuario), pero podrías filtrar por una tabla específica mediante el campo `o.name`.

Te dejo también [un ejercicio](http://rextester.com/IBKZM21820) para que puedas verificar el resultado en línea.

Las tablas del sistema (nombre con prefijo `sys`) tienen muchos campos útiles; te recomiendo que [leas sobre ellas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms179932.aspx) (o les hagas consultas directas) para revisar toda su estructura.